# R.string.name not displaying correctly

Tags: java, android

I am trying to concatenate a string declared in XML with another string but it just displays the ID number. What am I doing wrong?

```
 TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
 tv2.setText(R.string.task_name + " " + t.getName());
```

Output:

```
 2131034123 Sleep
```

Comment: The `R` class just contains static identifiers for resources.  Open it and have a look. There is nothing special about it, it is just another Java class.

Comment: if you look at `R.string.task_name` you'll see it is an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
tv2.setText(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.task_name) + " " + t.getName());
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to map it through your context. [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).

```
context.getString(R.string.MY_STRING);
```

Comment: Should I get the context for each TextView or other object when I create it? Or is it better to only get the context when I need to perform operations like I am doing now?

Comment: 'getString` is a method of `Context` so you only use it when needed :)

Comment: As others have pointed out, you can quickly get it from your activities via `getApplicationContext()`.